# How do I get the coordinates of an image size in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to get the coordinates for an image selected from the gallery.  When I go to gallery and select an image, the image is shown on screen.

The problem is the application gets the screen size, not the image size.

Relevant code:

```
targetImage.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener(){     

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    int x = (int) (event.getX() * imageWidth / v.getWidth());
    int y = (int) (event.getY() * imageHeight / v.getHeight());

    textView.setText("Touch coordinates : "+String.valueOf(event.getX())+" x "+String.valueOf(event.getY()));
    ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this line of code

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Thumbs up.
It is a good solution but it sets the width of the image to the screen, is there any other way that the application captures the image itself on screen?

Answer (score 1):

imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);